# A function with a bijection

Tags: probability, functions

Let $r:\Bbb N^*\to\Bbb Q$ a bijection and $r_n=r(n),\forall n\in\Bbb N^*$. $f_r$ is the function such that: $$\forall x \in \Bbb R, f_r(x)=\sum_{n\in I_x} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ where $$I_x=\{n \in \Bbb N^*/x-1 <r_n < x \}.$$  Let $C_r$  is the set of points where $f_r$ is continuous.

1. Show that $C_r$ is at most countable.
2. Can we find an $r$ such taht $f_r$ is  continuous?

Comment: If we take $g_{p}(x)=\sum_{x\leq r_n\leq x+\frac{1}{p}}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ this is equivalent to $g_p(x)-g_p(x-1)$ tends to $0$ when $p$ tends to $infinty$ for only a countable set of reals $x$